# Access objects inside a dinamically created HBox

Tags: javafx, controller, hbox

In the controller of my view, I created a list of HBoxes for the input of different values, each hbox consists of a textfield with an index number and two text boxes with information I want to retrieve. This is how I dynamically create each HBox.

```
void addRowToList() {
    HBox hb = new HBox(50);

    Text num = new Text(Integer.toString(numEdges + 1));
    hb.getChildren().add(num);

    TextField sep = new TextField();
    makeNumeric(sep);
    hb.getChildren().add(sep);

    TextField area = new TextField();
    makeNumeric(area);
    hb.getChildren().add(area);

    rows.add(hb);
}
```

After this, there is a point in which I need the information from those textBoxes in order to continue the execution of my program, my question is what is the method should I follow to access these since they don't have any given id? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getChildren()`?

Comment: If I use that, how can I differentiate between each of the items I got?

Comment: Use `instanceof`. And btw, they do have an ID. The order in which they were added in

Comment: @A.Gimeno by index????